# Email Subscription not working with Power BI Pro Trial version

Tags: email, powerbi

I have a power BI Pro Trial version, I subscribe for a report update on a daily basis. My dataset is updated several times per day, but I didn't get the email in my mail box.

No spam filter applied.

What can be the problem?
thx.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted the power BI support and we find that for receiving emails from power BI users must be registered into an AD.

Meaning that no AD no email!

The power BI PRO Trial license should work fine if the user is registered into AD.

AD=Active Directory.

Hope that this post can help someone!
Cheers!